# Reportlab - Table extend to multiple frames and pages

Tags: python, reportlab

I am trying to create a simple table in Reportlab which lists student names. However this table is 100+ rows long so will not fit on one page. I am looking for the table to split when it becomes too big to fit on one page, and continue on a second page and so on. I am also looking for the 'Student Report:' title to remain at the top of each page.

I have used the code below to do so but when I run the code for a table bigger than one page it runs indefinitely. I was hoping someone may be able to help me with this.

Thanks a million in advance, I really appreciate it!

```
import os
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from datetime import datetime as dt
from reportlab.pdfgen.canvas import Canvas
from reportlab.pdfgen import canvas
from reportlab.lib.styles import getSampleStyleSheet
from reportlab.lib import colors
from reportlab.platypus import Paragraph, Frame, Table, TableStyle, Image, Spacer
from reportlab.pdfbase import pdfmetrics
from reportlab.pdfbase.ttfonts import TTFont

#Pull in Student Names
student_names = pd.read_csv("test_names.csv")

#Define table style
tblstyle = TableStyle([('INNERGRID', (0,0), (-1,-1), 0.25, colors.white),
                           ('BOX', (0,0), (-1,-1), 0.25, colors.white),
                           ('FONTSIZE', (0, 0), (-1, 0), 6),
                           ('FONTSIZE', (0, 1), (-1, -1), 6),
                           ('TEXTFONT', (0, 0), (-1, 0), 'Calibri-Bold'),
                           ('TEXTFONT', (0, 1), (0, -1), 'Calibri-Bold'),
                           ('TEXTFONT', (0, 1), (-1, -1), 'Calibri'),
                           ('TEXTCOLOR', (0, 0), (-1, 0), colors.white),
                           ('TEXTCOLOR', (1, 1), (0, -1), colors.black),
                           ('LEFTPADDING', (0, 0), (-1, -1), 1),
                           ('RIGHTPADDING', (0, 0), (-1, -1), 1),
                           ('TOPPADDING', (0, 0), (-1, -1), 0),
                           ('BOTTOMPADDING', (0, 0), (-1, -1), 0),
                           ('ROWBACKGROUNDS', (0, 0), (-1, -1), (colors.HexColor('#e8e9ec'), colors.HexColor('#CED1D6'))),
                           ('BACKGROUND', (0, 0), (-1, 0), colors.HexColor('#3A5675')),
                           ('ALIGN', (0, 0), (-1, 0), 'CENTER'),
                           ('ALIGN', (0, 1), (-1, -1), 'CENTER'),
                           ('VALIGN', (0, 0), (-1, -1), 'BOTTOM'),
                           ])

#Create a document
c = canvas.Canvas("student_list.pdf")
dtstring = dt.date.today().strftime("%B %d, %Y")

#create header on first page
c.drawString(55,750,"Student Report: "+dtstring)
c.line(50,740,530,740)

# turn datatable the table into a list of lists which is the format reportlab wants
data_summary = [pd.DataFrame(student_names).columns.values.tolist()] + pd.DataFrame(student_names).values.tolist()

# config the widths and heights of this specific table
colwidths_2 = [300] * len(data_summary)
rowheights_2 = [15] * len(data_summary)
    
# create table using the platypus Table object & set the style
tbl_summary = Table(data_summary,colwidths_2,rowheights_2,hAlign='LEFT', repeatRows=1)
tbl_summary.setStyle(tblstyle)

# Create frame empty story       
frame = Frame(50, 15, 500, 700, showBoundary=1)
story = []

story.append(tbl_summary)

for t in story:
    while frame.add(t, c) == 0:
        frame.split(t, c)
        frame = Frame(50, 15, 500, 700, showBoundary=1)

# save pdf
c.save()

os.startfile('student_list.pdf')
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think what you're running into is that a canvas is a single page.  You need to use a document template so the flowable knows what to do when it gets to the end of the page.

... I don't have Pandas or Numpy so I couldn't test this, and the 1st page header & spacer will likely to need adjusting, but I think you want something like:

```
import os
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from datetime import datetime as dt
from reportlab.pdfgen.canvas import Canvas
from reportlab.pdfgen import canvas
from reportlab.lib.pagesizes import letter
from reportlab.lib.units import inch
from reportlab.lib.styles import getSampleStyleSheet
from reportlab.lib import colors
from reportlab.platypus import Paragraph, Frame, Table, TableStyle, Image, Spacer, SimpleDocTemplate
from reportlab.pdfbase import pdfmetrics
from reportlab.pdfbase.ttfonts import TTFont

# Pull in Student Names
student_names = pd.read_csv("test_names.csv")

# Define table style
tblstyle = TableStyle([('INNERGRID', (0, 0), (-1, -1), 0.25, colors.white),
                       ('BOX', (0, 0), (-1, -1), 0.25, colors.white),
                       ('FONTSIZE', (0, 0), (-1, 0), 6),
                       ('FONTSIZE', (0, 1), (-1, -1), 6),
                       ('TEXTFONT', (0, 0), (-1, 0), 'Calibri-Bold'),
                       ('TEXTFONT', (0, 1), (0, -1), 'Calibri-Bold'),
                       ('TEXTFONT', (0, 1), (-1, -1), 'Calibri'),
                       ('TEXTCOLOR', (0, 0), (-1, 0), colors.white),
                       ('TEXTCOLOR', (1, 1), (0, -1), colors.black),
                       ('LEFTPADDING', (0, 0), (-1, -1), 1),
                       ('RIGHTPADDING', (0, 0), (-1, -1), 1),
                       ('TOPPADDING', (0, 0), (-1, -1), 0),
                       ('BOTTOMPADDING', (0, 0), (-1, -1), 0),
                       ('ROWBACKGROUNDS', (0, 0), (-1, -1), (colors.HexColor('#e8e9ec'), colors.HexColor('#CED1D6'))),
                       ('BACKGROUND', (0, 0), (-1, 0), colors.HexColor('#3A5675')),
                       ('ALIGN', (0, 0), (-1, 0), 'CENTER'),
                       ('ALIGN', (0, 1), (-1, -1), 'CENTER'),
                       ('VALIGN', (0, 0), (-1, -1), 'BOTTOM'),
                       ])



# Create a document
c = canvas.Canvas("student_list.pdf")

# turn datatable the table into a list of lists which is the format reportlab wants
data_summary = [pd.DataFrame(student_names).columns.values.tolist()] + pd.DataFrame(student_names).values.tolist()

# config the widths and heights of this specific table
colwidths_2 = [300] * len(data_summary)
rowheights_2 = [15] * len(data_summary)

# create table using the platypus Table object & set the style
tbl_summary = Table(data_summary, colwidths_2, rowheights_2, hAlign='LEFT', repeatRows=1)
tbl_summary.setStyle(tblstyle)


# Build Story - Add a spacer at the beginning for your heading
story = [
    Spacer(1, 1 * inch)
]

story.append(tbl_summary)

# Create Page 1 Formatting
def myFirstPage(canvas: canvas.Canvas, doc):
    canvas.saveState()

    dtstring = dt.date.today().strftime("%B %d, %Y")

    # create header on first page
    canvas.drawString(55, 750, "Student Report: " + dtstring)
    canvas.line(50, 740, 530, 740)


# Use a Document Template so the flowable can flow to the next page.  
doc = SimpleDocTemplate(
    "student_list.pdf",
    pageSize=letter,
    rightMargin=0.5 * inch, leftMargin=0.5 * inch, topMargin=0.5 * inch, bottomMargin=0.5 * inch,
)

# Build and save
doc.build(story, onFirstPage=myFirstPage)
```

EDIT:  Adding a link to a great answer about layout across multiple pages:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/39268987/5679079

Comment: Thanks a million Alex, really appreciate the help on this one!